# Magento Web Serice, REST or Soap

Tags: android, web-services, magento, soap

We are creating an Android APP with the Magento webservice.  There are two type of web service: Soap and Rest.  Which way is better?

I digged a bit online, many people says REST has better performance than Soap?(not sure why).

Yet it seems the Magento Community doesn't develop all the functions for REST APIs, so shall I develop the APP with combination of using REST and Soap?

Anyone shred a light please, thanks in advance.

Comment: There is already an active discussion regarding this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454251/android-app-for-magento-store-using-rest-or-soap